# Moq abstract class Property is NULL when cast as interface

Tags: c#, interface, properties, moq

I've got some weird behaviour in Moq 4.2. When I make a mock of an abstract class which implements an interface which defines properties, I can access the properties just fine, as long as the instance is the original type. If I cast that instance to the underlying interface, the properties return default values.

See below for an example. Anyone have a solution to this?
In the example below, doing `foo.As<IFoo>()` does not help.

```
public interface IFoo { string Thingy { get; } }
public abstract class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo() { Thingy = "Howdy"; }
    public string Thingy { get; }
}
public class Test
{
    public void DoIt()
    {
        var foo = new Mock<Foo>();
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Object.Thingy);              // prints "Howdy"
        Console.WriteLine((foo.Object as IFoo).Thingy);    // prints nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is what you want - Moq mocks interface implementations, but can't mock non-interface/non-virtual method/properties. The fact you made one to be both non-interface property and interface property unnecessaryly confusing...

Comment: Why do you want to access `Thingy` through the interface?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* I want to access Thingy through the interface? It's a contrived example here to show the issue. How my tests are actually failing is when my mocked object is passed elsewhere in the code via an interface. Programming to an interface is pretty standard fare today, so it's surprising to see Moq failing like this.

Answer (score 0):

Mock - generates a proxy of some object with its own implementation.

1. proxyImpl1 : IFoo { string Thingy => default }
   call Thingy return proxied property
2. proxyImpl : Foo {nothing, since the parent object does not contain virtual methods} call Thingy return parent non-overrided property.
   POCO works the same way in EF